# TestNG parallel DataProvider

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'd like to run test methods in a class parallely with data provider.
I would need a data provider that gets called every time before a new test method starts to generate partly dynamic data for the given test run. Let me explain it in pseudo code:

```
@DataProvider(parallel=true)
public Object[][] dp(){
  User user = createNewUser();
  return new Object[][]{
            {"s1", new AExtendsOtherObject(user), user},
            {"s2", new BExtendsOtherObject("any"), user},
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dp")
void test(String s, OtherObject o, User user){
}

<suite name="all" verbose="1" parallel="methods" data-provider-thread-count="5">
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so now that I realised what I really want my question looks a bit stupid. Sorry for that. Anyway, here is my solution:

```
@DataProvider(parallel=true)
public Iterator<Object[]> dp(){
  List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
  User user = createNewUser();
  list.add(new Object[]{"s1", new AExtendsOtherObject(user), user});
  user = createNewUser();
  list.add(new Object[] {"s2", new BExtendsOtherObject("any"), user});        
  return list.iterator();
}
```

The only problem with this solution is that if the createNewUser() takes a lot of time then it will take it upfront at once before any test method could start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this? From the public doc:

https://howtodoinjava.com/testng/testng-executing-parallel-tests/#test_in_multiple_threads

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I could not find out how that feature could help in this case.